# getting multiple marker coordinates in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hi to all the members of this great community!

This is my first question so forgive me for possible mistakes. I hope that from this day on i can be helpful for some of you as hopefully you will be for me.Getting to the question:

I am building an android app whose purpose is to search for nearest fuel-points and nearest care-repair-centers. I am very new to android and thx to the numerous posts about android in here I have managed to reach the point where i have build the map and animate it to my current location while updating my location.

Now i have to add the markers of the points of interest. Since they are at least 10 (I will add them only for demonstration purposes) i think it's not wise to add them through 10+ repetitive calls to `itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem()`. My idea was to save them in a file in the format `( " latitude " , "longitude" , simple_description_title , other info )` and than in some way import the first 2 fields for the geopoint and the 3rd for the title. 
I will use than the 4th later for some type of tooltip text (for example tel_number).

Do you think this is a good approach? And how can I implement the file reading(if) in the code that `extends ItemizeOverlay()`.

I didn't post the code until this point since it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, let's jump right into your problem/question.

1.) Since you are only adding 10 points of interest it won't matter if you just call itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem() for all 10 because the trick is to call itemizedOverlay.populate() only after you have added all the overlayItems using itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem(), this way you don't compromise on performance.

2.) Now, once again, since you are only doing a demonstration I would advise you to simply hard-code all the 10 overlays with their respective geolocations into the Android code itself. This way you WON'T have to worry about reading data. Also, using a txt file to store data isn't the best option both performance and convenience wise. This is what databases exist for.

3.) If, and when you do this in the future, you do need to use some dynamic data to populate your markers with, then I'd STRONGLY advise you to use either

- SQLite: The embedded database that Android offers, it's great for storing small bits of information that's required for your application such as description title, other info, the latitude, longitude, however, if you have some sort of a connection based application where you need to update globally accessible data every once in a while I'd advise you to use the next option,
- MySQL: This is an online database that you have to interface with using a server and PHP. The advantage of using an online database is that you can now share information between different users (friends, contacts, followers etc.) by reading and writing to and from the database.

Comment: Thx for the response. I tried to use SQLite as you suggested but some problems arised as i will post in my response.